# How can I operate image in class ASyncTask without blocking UI thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My code is as follows:

```
private ImageView imageAvatar;
private Drawable image;
private BitmapDrawable drawable;

protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
    image = ImageOperations(url);
    imageAvatar.setImageDrawable(image);
    imageAvatar.setMinimumHeight(32);
    imageAvatar.setMinimumWidth(32);
    imageAvatar.setMaxHeight(128);
    imageAvatar.setMaxWidth(128);
    IsFinish = true;
    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageAvatar.getDrawable();
    if(drawable != null) {
        return drawable.getBitmap();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I retrieve data by `taskImage.execute().get()`. I know that `get()` would wait if necessary for the computation. I have to implement my code on `onPostExecute()` to prevent blocking UI thread.

The problem is: if I want to operate my code in `onPostExecute()` to prevent blocking UI thread, the result should not be `Bitmap`, but I want to retrieve `Bitmap` from `ASyncTask`.

What should I do?

Comment: Store the `Bitmap` result in a member variable? Using `get()`, as you are, *will* block the UI thread, so you cannot do it in this way. It's hard to help you without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: you will need to put your code inside onPostExecute method and start ASyncTask without calling get method

Comment: You mean I have to use `taskimage.execute()`, and how can I get my data from `ASyncTask`?

Comment: @barssala : you will get data back as bitmap inside onPostExecute method when doInBackground execution complete  just move your code inside onPostExecute